# My HTML Form element closing itself before even input element started

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, element

i tried to edit this soo much times but unable to do so. Please help me.
There is php Code also But it is not showing down. Above this is the if statement for the result more than zero and the only problem i got is that gender checked is working only in one form and in other form the gender checked don't worked. The form element is closing itself after starting. Please Help me i shall be thankful to you.
My Code is here.

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>S.NO.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $srnumber++;
            ?> 
            <tr class="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> tablerow">
                <td><?php echo $srnumber;?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td3"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td4"><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td5"><?php echo $row['address'];?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td6"><?php echo $row['city'];?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td7"><?php echo $row['state'];?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td8"><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
                <td class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> td9"><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                <td><a onclick="userupdateclick(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" class="update" data-value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Update</a></td>
                <td><a href="#"></a></td>
                <td><a onclick="deleteuser(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" href="#" class="delete" data-value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> datavalue" style="display: none;">
                <form action="dashboard.php" method="post" id="updateform" class="<?php echo $row['id'];?> formclass">
                    <td><?php echo $srnumber;?></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="upid" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                        <input type="text" name='upname' id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name='upemail' id="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name='upaddress' id="address" value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>"></td>
                    <td><select name="upcity" id="city">
                            <option  id="blankcity" value="blankcity"></option>
                            <option value="jalandhar" id="jalandhar" <?php if($row['city']=="jalandhar"){echo 'selected';} ?> >Jalandhar</option>
                            <option value="chandigarh" id="chandigarh" <?php if($row['city']=="chandigarh"){echo 'selected';} ?> >Chandigarh</option>
                            <option value="new_chandigarh" id="new_chandigarh" <?php if($row['city']=="new_chandigarh"){echo 'selected';} ?>>New Chandigarh</option>
                            <option value="panchkula" id="panchkula" <?php if($row['city']=="panchkula"){echo 'selected';} ?> >Panchkula</option>
                            <option value="sirsa" id="sirsa" <?php if($row['city']=="sirsa"){echo 'selected';} ?> >Sirsa</option>
                            <option value="mohali" id="mohali" <?php if($row['city']=="mohali"){echo 'selected';} ?> >Mohali</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select name="upstate" id="state">
                            <option id="blankstate" value="blankstate" ></option>
                            <option value="punjab" id="punjab" <?php if($row['state']=="punjab"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Punjab</option>
                            <option value="hariyana" id="hariyana" <?php if($row['state']=="hariyana"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Hariyana</option>
                            <option value="chandigarh" id="schandigarh" <?php if($row['state']=="chandigarh"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Chandigarh</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name='upphone' id="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="upgender" value="male" id="male" <?php if($row['gender']=='male'){echo 'checked';} ?>>Male
                        <input type="radio" name="upgender" value="female" id="female" <?php if($row['gender']=='female'){echo 'checked';} ?>>female</td>
                        <td><a type="button" onclick="usersaveupdate(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" href="#" class="saveupdate" data-value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Save </a></td>
                        <td><a onclick="usercancelclick(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" href="#" class="cancel" data-value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Cancel</a></td>
                        <td><a onclick="deleteuserform(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" href="#" class="delete" data-value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Welcome. `<form></form>` is not allowed between `<tr>` elements. Place the `<form>` tag before your `<table>` and your `</form>` tag after your `</table>`. Don't know if that helps in any way, didn't quite get your problem.

Comment: If i placed the form tag before the table tag then there will only one form. But i want to loop through the forms and want to make as much form as the users in the database.

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact, that you have to follow HTML rules. A form simply can not be placed at this position in a table. It either has to be around the whole table, or located inside a single table cell. _“The form element is closing itself after starting”_ - the browser’s error correction mechanism does that, _because_ of the illegal nesting of elements you produced here.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering i will take care of this next time.

Comment: What about the while loop, it's not closing correctly in the code.. Either not at all. This must be before the closing table tag. Try this.

Comment: it is not showing the php code in this windows but i already did this as you said already. The main problem was the table tag. We can't place our form tag inside Table tag that's why the form tag was closing itself

Comment: @CrackIt - There's nothing stopping you from putting one/multiple forms within any given table. You just need to observe the rules when it comes to opening and closing tags. There's no reason why you couldn't have a separate form with a different action in each and every cell of a table. A form can exist in a cell. Also a form can completely enclose a table.